# Query that executes correctly in mysql client returns empty results in PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am stuck trying to figure out why a query that works in mysql does not work in CodeIgniter. Here's the code:

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where('table.project_id', $project_id);
    $this->db->where('table.user_id', $user_id);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $result = $q->result();
    log_message('error', 'error message='.$this->db->_error_message());
    log_message('error', 'error number='.$this->db->_error_number());
    log_message('error', 'result='.print_r($result, true));
    log_message('error', 'last query='.$this->db->last_query());
```

The log output on this looks like this:

```
ERROR - 2013-09-20 08:53:03 --> error message=
ERROR - 2013-09-20 08:53:03 --> error number=0
ERROR - 2013-09-20 08:53:03 --> result=Array
(
)

ERROR - 2013-09-20 08:53:03 --> last query=SELECT `table`.*
FROM (`table`)
WHERE `table`.`project_id` =  '99'
AND `table`.`user_id` =  '1927'
```

When I run the query in mysql I get:

```
mysql> SELECT `table`.*
    -> FROM (`table`)
    -> WHERE `table`.`project_id` =  '99'
    -> AND `table`.`user_id` =  '1927';
+------+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
| id   | user_id | group_id | project_id | accepted_terms |
+------+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
| 2328 |    1927 |        8 |         99 |              0 |
+------+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the query that CI is constructing is valid, and it returns a result set in the mysql client. However, the query returns an empty Array in CodeIgniter. There are many, many other queries that are working on this page. I can't for the life of me figure out why this query isn't working in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Try it without active record, just for the sake of debugging. `$q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE project_id = 99 AND user_id = 1927');` Also, try to print_r($result);die(); before you do any logging and see if you still get no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in a die statement after your log_message entries, run the code again and see if you still see the result when you manually run the query.  It is possible that the code you see is correct and somewhere else is inserting the data.

Comment: tom: that was it...the record got added after the query!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and try once:

```
$result = $q->result();
```

To:

```
$result = $q->result_array();
```

Comment: Sorry, no luck...exact same output.